# A crash on a curly bracket: debug assertion faild

Tags: debugging, crash, visual-c++-2008

I have a piece of code that runs in debug mode in VS2008, C++.
The problem is that when I am debugging the code line by line, at a very weird point of the code, it crashes and says:

> **debug assertion faild. 
>   Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)**

The crash point is on the first closed curly bracket (after mesh->edges[e].needsUpdate=false;)
I don't understand why on a curly bracket? does that make sense to you guys?

What is going on?

```
for(int e=0; e<mesh->edges.size(); e++)
{
    if(mesh->edges[e].valid && mesh->edges[e].v[0]>=0 && mesh->edges[e].v[1]>=0 &&
        mesh->points[mesh->edges[e].v[0]].writable && mesh->points[mesh->edges[e].v[1]].writable)
    {
        //update v_hat and its corresponding error
        DecEdge Current = DecEdge(e);
        pair<Point, float> ppf = computeVhat(e);
        Current.v_hat = ppf.first;
        Current.error = ppf.second;

        edgeSoup.push(Current);
        mesh->edges[e].needsUpdate=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what has happened with this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, crashes that happen on a closing brace mean that the crash happened in a destructor that ran when the block went out of scope.  I'd check what's happening in the destructors for `DecEdge` and `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have deleted any of the pointers that u have used. This can be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have some libraries compiled in DEBUG mode and some in RELEASE mode.